# Vectors and representation of lines

Tags: vectors

Given vectors $p$ and $d$, we can describe the line through $p$ in direction $d$ as the vectors $x$ that satisfy
$x = p + t d$

In this problem we explore another representation for lines.

a) Let $p = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $d = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$. Find vectors $q$ and $n$ such that the line described above can also be described as the vectors $x$ that satisfy
$(x - q) \bullet n = 0.$

b) Show that for any $p$ and nonzero $d$, there exist vectors $q$ and $n$ so that a vector $x$ lies on the line
$x = p + td$
if and only if
$(x - q) \bullet n = 0.$

Im so confused! Can I have some help please? Thank you!!! :)

Comment: What's your background? Are you familiar with linear algebra?

Comment: Yes, I'm just having problems on this question specifically

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** $\vec n \cdot (\vec x - \vec p)=0$ represents the same line with $\vec x= \vec p + t \vec d$. This equation is called the normal form. So, if $\vec q=\vec p$, then the result is obvious. If you choose $\vec q$ different from $\vec p$, as long as $\vec q$ is on the same line, the normal form $\vec n \cdot (\vec x - \vec q)=0$ will be still valid for the same $\vec n$. In this case, you just change the base point of the line representation. You can test it by setting $\vec q=\vec p + \vec d$ for $t=1$ (or you can choose any other value of $t$). As you see, you can pick any other point with respect to parameter $t$, and the normal $\vec n$ won't change. This satisfies the "there exists" argument.