# Prove that all linear combination $c{\bf v}+d{\bf w}$ with $c+d=1$ is a line?

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that all linear combination $c\boldsymbol{v}+d\boldsymbol{ w}$ with $c+d=1$ is a line in 2D, where $\boldsymbol{ v}$ and $\boldsymbol{ w}$ are nonzero vectors in 2D.

Comment: what is your definition of line, and what are $v$ and $w$?

Comment: if v=w=0 this is not true

Comment: More generally if $v=w$ this is not true

Comment: @M.Van Thanks, I just edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If one only one of both vectors is zero the statement is trivial. Assume $v-w\neq 0$. Now, observe: $cv+dw=(1-d)v+dw=v+d(w-v)$

$w-v$ is the vector for the direction of the line. $d$ is the parameter that we vary from $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $v$ is a point on the line. This is nothing but the vectorial representation of a line. See also this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375617/vectors-and-representation-of-lines).

Comment: Hi, can you go on giving me more hint, please? I still have problem seeing the line out of this equation.

Comment: Pardon me if I am asking a silly question: from what you said here, $v+d(w-v)$ doesn't follow the computation rule of vectors? Because I think this is just an vector addition between $v$ and $d(w-v)$. If I'm right, then the direction of  $v+d(w-v)$ varies with $d$. Please help me here

Comment: No $d$ just scales the vector $w-v$ because it is a scalar.